# Is there a difference between requiring modules at the top of a file vs. inline with code

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, dependencies, require

For example let's say you have a CLI tool written in node that only needs to load a module when a certain flag is passed.

Is there any difference if I have `require('dependency')` at the top of the file or if I have it inside of the branch i.e.

```
if (theFlagWasPassed) {
  const dependency = require('dependency')
}
```

Comment: I think there is no difference, but the good practice is put it at the top and make it global. `var variable = required('dependency');`

Comment: @KenrySanchez I am under that impression as well, but I'm asking because someone else brought it up and I realized I don't have a definitive answer. The node docs were very unhelpful so I was wondering if someone knows the behavior more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Nearly every programmer will look at the first few lines to find the dependencies. Inline imports are a bad idea for readability.

There is also a performance concern (cant be optimized that much, however thats just a guess) thats why the new `import` statement must be at the highest scope.

Comment: Agreed, but what I'm wondering is not a matter of style/readability, but rather if there is any actual difference with regards to if a module is required or not, and what the performance implications are. This isn't something that I ever do, but is something that I'm curious about. For example, this is why the [dynamic import proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) exists, but I don't think that applies to the vanilla nodejs require. Thus I'm curious if putting a require behind a branch changes anything.

Comment: @m0meni well its `imported module workload * branch probability` compared to `V8 optimizations`. There are too many variables to actually come up with an exact answer